# Exporting Cycles Sky to skybox images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

I followed a tutorial [Adding Clouds to Blender Cycles' Sky Texture](https://youtu.be/Tr6wTyfAO04) on how to generate a nice sky in Blender with good  results.
Now I want to  export the sky as 6 images for making a skybox in my game engine (Esenthel). I tried with rotating the camera in the six directions needed( front, back, left, right, up and down) and saved the renders, but that didn't work to good as I got visible seams when applied in my engine skybox.

Do anyone have an advice on how to do this export correctly?

Comment: Does [**this entry in the wiki**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Render/Panoramic) help? (It is for 2.4, but is still relevant)

Comment: You may also find [**this BlenderArtist's thread**](http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-241187.html) to be of interest.

Comment: If you can use an equirectangular panoramic sky instead of a cube, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13431/how-do-i-bake-an-animated-sky-box-using-cycles might be useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can UVmap a cube and add a Glossy Material to it.  Set the Roughness parameter to 0.0
Add a Sub-Surface Modifier to the cube and set it to about 4 iterations, this helps for baking the Glossy Shader properly.

Add a texture node to the material so the sky can be baked to the UV Coordinates.

[image]

Now invert the faces for the cube so they face inwards. This should work as a SkyBox.

[image]

If you want the sky to be available in a GLSL shader as a reflection map then you may want to pay closer attention to how the UV's are laid out since a game engine may have specific layout requirements for skybox/enviroment/cubeMaps.

Here's some reference on how to code a cubemap using a runtime technique that was published by nVidia, it uses nVidia CG which is a shader language that is compatible with both OpenGL and DirectX.

https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160408223256/http://http.developer.nvidia.com:80/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter07.html

And the source code to go along with the CgTutorial

https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit-download

Comment: "Please avoid text in images" - [David](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2217/david)

Comment: I've tried this method but when I try to add a subsurf modifier the bakes images are very distorted around the edges. I rendered each face to a seperate image tho, not sure if that's the problem. I removed the subsurf and the bake seems to be rendering fine tho.