# Cycles - Skybox using 6 projected images

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have generated 6 images that are of a sky projected onto the faces of a cube from the viewpoint of the centre of the cube (ie. a hopefully seamless skybox).

However I am having issues adding this texture to the world material. I have tried adding the images to the background via an Environment Texture but am unable to get anything even remotely close to looking correct.

Here are my problems:

1. The world material seems to be applied to a sphere but I want it to be a box (the program I am using to generate the sky generates a box)
2. I don't know how to stitch my images together for use in the world material
3. I'm not sure I'm even going about this the right way

I have searched and searched trying different things for most of the day so far but am coming up blank.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting Cycles Sky to skybox images](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28328/exporting-cycles-sky-to-skybox-images)

Comment: Cycles's environment object does not support skybox textures. Your best bet is to place the scene inside a large cube object with your texture mapped to it.

Comment: @poor Not the same question in my opinion. One has 6 images and wants to use them, one has sky and wants to export to 6 images: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question

Comment: @RayMairlot ok, you are right. retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender's environment texture in Cycles only supports Mirror Ball and Equirectangular image map types. You cannot use a skybox texture directly.

Some of your options are:

1. Convert the skybox image to one of the other 2 formats in a third party image convertor.
2. Set Blender native environment to pure black. Create a large cube object that surrounds your scene, UV unwrap and add the skybox image texture to that object.
3. Find a new sky image in Equirectangular or Mirrorball format and use that instead

Blender's internal render engine (BI) does seem to support additional mapping types (Object, Tube, Sphere, Global). Perhaps you could use the Object mode to base the mapping on a cube object but displayed as the world environment. I've not tried or tested that technique though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was coming to the conclusion that it was not directly possible but needed confirmation. I do not know of any software that can convert my images... apart from blender xD I think I will apply it to a cube in another scene and generate the environment map from that then use that generated one in my original scene (hopefully I won't lose too much detail, but I can generate higher resolution images of my skybox as it is procedurally generated so I have a workaround). This should work and shouldn't take too long.