# How can I render a cubemap with Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I need to render a cubemap from a Blender scene.

Is this the correct way to do it?:

Set camera FOV to 90.
Have one camera facing up, one down, left, right, front , back.
Is that all to achieve a proper seamless cubemap?

If not, how then?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32493/cycles-skybox-using-6-projected-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of which render engine you use, the process is the same.

It has been explained well [**here**](https://github.com/Senscape/Dagon/wiki/Using-Blender-to-make-cube-maps).

> ### Setup the Blender Render Panel
>
> Enter a resolution in the Render Panel and ensure the aspect ratio is
> set equal. [(e.g., 1024x1024)]
>
> ### Setup a camera
>
> . . .
>
> - Set the camera's 'Lens' to 'perspective' and Field of View to 90 degrees exactly.
> - Put the camera's location at the center of wherever the viewpoint will be in the modeling environment.
> - There are six images for each cube face.
> - The camera rotation values that correspond to each cube face are: (x,y,z values in degrees)
>
> > ```
> > North:  90,0,0
> > East:   90,0,-90
> > South:  90,0,-180
> > West:   90,0,90
> > Up:     180,0,0
> > Down:   0,0,0
> > ```
>
> - Set the camera to each rotation and render the image, then save each image
>
> . . .

---

Personally I find rendering a single-image equirectangular environment map to be easier, but I understand you may have specific reasons for needing a cube map.

Comment: I'd prefer equirectangular rendering myself, but Blender Internal doesnt support it which I need to use.

Comment: So basically yes, I was right (for anyone who doesn't want to bother to read the link).

Comment: Please include some of the steps for rendering in the answer itself instead of just linking to the solution. Link only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does this answer.

Comment: Please expand on the link and make your answer useful here. As it is now all your answer does, is direct someone to where they can get the info. Se answer should have the info here.

Comment: The problem with equirectangular maps is there are wasted pixels at the poles, and not enough resolution at the equator.  Cubemaps have their own problems, of course, but tradeoffs aren't a surprise to anyone here...