# Skybox problems: make islands have ZERO margin?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, uv-image-editor

Ok, I no doubt did this incorrectly but I manually arranged my unwrapped UVs (after Smart project) onto my linear laid out skybox image - on the whole I need some pointers as to whether Im doing this right, but what I did was per [Cycles - Skybox using 6 projected images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32493/cycles-skybox-using-6-projected-images) (im in cycles)-

I unwrapped my image onto a cube and subdivided into a sphere:

[image]

And just made it huge. My issue is, packing islands gets me this:

[image]

And I have an issue with the margins between the islands, which creates these seams clearly:

[image]

Whats the best route to optimize this skybox here/get rid of the margins neatly?

Comment: For rendering skyboxes, I just set up the camera to be square with a FOV of 90deg exactly, go through six frames of animation, and render each face as a separate frame. I think I've done this with Unity too with no problems.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the blender version of this? Are you talking about spinning the cube or what?

Comment: Instead of having a cube, have a camera in the center of the scene and "take pictures" in each direction (one image per cube face: up, down, left, right, front, back). This gives you rendered frames that can be applied as individual faces of the cube map. You don't actually need a cube in your scene, you're just using the main camera.

Answer (score 0):

I like to create skybox with uv sphere, it's simpler and easier.
Do a quick search on youtube on how to create skybox in the blender that you learn in 5 min.

It will look good like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: No - I need to use this image/cube mapped. Its already plugged into Unity, not going to switch back and forth

Comment: Do not use subdivision surface. Cubic mapping has to stay as it stands. And apply shadeless on the material to keep out dark corners.

Comment: Ok, thanks but doesnt fix my problem with those seams