# Adding Cubemaps to materials

Tags: materials

is there a way to add Cubemaps, to a specific material? Do Cubemaps work at all in Blender 2.81? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello :). [This Stack Exchange thread might help you.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32493/78972)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help, I'm trying to add reflections to a material from cubemaps, not to create a skybox :(