# Export Skybox for Games

Tags: uv, export

I'm trying to make a Skybox in Blender with a cube and multiple UV maps. My workflow till now: Added a cube -> added 6 Uv maps under Data panel -> new Material -> new Texture. I don't understand how to get UV information on each face of the cube to the specific UV Map. I tried to add another UV Map then selected the face and Unwrapped it, but that doesn't work. How do I do this? And also, do I need 6 Materials or is 1 Material with 6 different textures also possible? <3

Edit: I want to import everything into the Unreal Engine, and I need 2048 Resolution on each face.

Comment: Could you clarify what your workflow is?

Comment: If I had a workflow I wouldn't ask, I just want a skybox for the Unreal Engine. I found this wonderful tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3sN0ZQDEpY) but it's for 3DS Max and they are using ID mask or something which I thought are just multiple UV's.

Answer (score 3):

Each [UVmap](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv/unwrapping.html) always contains the UV coordinates of **all** the object's faces.

If the **material is the same for each face**, I would suggest to make **1 material with 1 big texture** that contains all 6 individual textures. Each face's UV island should cover to only a portion of the UV layout as it's done in this related answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28349/15140

[image]

This is just one of the possible UV layouts. Sometimes can be useful to have a 3x2 matrix of images and using a rectangular texture... it dependes on your needs.

Comment: Does it make any sense to change the material for each face? 
I want to import everything into the Unreal Engine, so I need 2048 Resolution on each face... Is your suggestion to make a 6k texture?!