# can i take a texture from blender cycles into BGE?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine

I spent a while working on the floor for a forest bump map but it wont work in BGE. Is there any way i can make the bump map work in BGE?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98201/transferring-materials-made-in-cycles-render-to-blender-game-engine and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28328/exporting-cycles-sky-to-skybox-images and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles

Comment: yes but i want to keep my bump map.