# render scene TO a skydome

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity

Is it possible to render my scene into a skydome?

I created a lowpoly game I want the sky with clouds and mountains in the back of the scene to be in a skydome (in Unity) and just the ground with the trees and that stuff to be actual mesh.

I'm developing VR for cardboard so trying to minimize the polys in scene but .. I need control over the background, cannot just go and download a texture.

PS: I've been told that for VR skybox is not adviced and skydome is the way to go. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13431/how-do-i-bake-an-animated-sky-box-using-cycles/13435#13435

Comment: Does Unity take equirectangular environment maps? How about cube maps? If it can use either of those, [see this.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/how-to-render-an-environment-to-a-cube-map-in-cycles)

Comment: @Mentalist I've been dealing with it and I would really say it does not :(

Any other clue ?

Comment: I got curious and decided to RTFM. Unity takes cube maps, essentially. But instead of one texture, it uses 6 individual ones. This info can be found in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html). So you can simply [follow these steps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47174) up to the part about compositing, and stop there because instead of compositing you will load each of the 6 images into Unity individually.

Comment: As for a "skybox" vs a "skydome" where VR is concerned, the most info I was able to find with a quick search was in [this thread](https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/760/skyboxes) on the Oculus forums. Read the comment by user Pyry. And as a result of what I read there I then found [this other thread discussing a Rift-specific skybox](https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/844/how-to-apply-the-rift-specific-skybox/p2). I don't know much about Unity or Oculus, but I know that Unity supports cube maps, so why don't you try that and let me know how it goes? I'm curious too.

Comment: as far as I read (did not check your link yet) skybox performs per-pixel operations that are not welcome in VR environment. What I tried so far (and seems to be working) I created a mirror sfere in the center of the blender scene and I bake its surface. At the end I get one UV sphere with a texture that shows all the image around... not bad so far .. .