# Blender No Equilateral type in camera lens

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

In blender I don't have the "type" option under lens for the camera object.

[image]

I really would like to use the equirectangular..

Blender version 2.78c

Comment: possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13435/660

Answer (score 5):

You must be in Cycles to access this option:

[image]